# Lewis structure of a compound

Tags: organic-chemistry

What is the correct lewis structure of ammonium cyanate  ion? I do have a structure but it seems partially correct. If I'm wrong, then please inform that also.    [image]

Comment: $\ce{NH3 }$ has a lone pair, $\ce{NH4^+ }$ doesn't.

Comment: What lone pair? NH4+ has none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that there will be no lone pair in nitrogen as the  lone pair is donated to the 4th H+ ion. This forms the ammonium ion.

Now, cyanate ion is formed by [OCN]-. The negative charge is due to the three lone pairs in O (instead of two). [image]